# how to call web method in c# without jquery

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-web-api

Here i write a code in which i want to hit a soap web method i know how to hit web api but new in soap application so please let me know how to call without jquery

```
       using (HttpClient httpClientObj = new HttpClient())
        {
           httpClientObj.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1172/");
            httpClientObj.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClientObj.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseObj = default(HttpResponseMessage);
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(clsSSL.AcceptAllCertifications);
            responseObj = httpClientObj.PostAsJsonAsync("FairPriceShopRequestAck", val).Result;
            string responseReturnString = null;
            responseReturnString = responseObj.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if ((responseObj.IsSuccessStatusCode & responseObj.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseObj.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
            else
            {
                //showMessageAjax(this, responseReturnString);
            }

            return "";
        }
```

Getting error http 500

Comment: can you pls elaborate little more?

Comment: Is 3rd-party libraries an option?

Comment: @rafique simple i want to hit a api that's soap based i am not able to hit web method using the above programm

Comment: didnt get u @smoksness

Comment: If you want to use a Web API I assume it's a restful(-like) service, and then I can recommend using RestShartp. http://restsharp.org/ If that's an option, then I can provide som example-code.

Comment: Without knowing the expected input by the service and the contents of "val" is nearly impossible to see what's happening.

Comment: okay leave just let me know simply how to call web method of soap in c# forget what i mentioned above

Comment: @gusman Val is collection of argument that i have to pass in the method

Comment: Yes, and it's an string, it's obvious, what I mean is the structure of the data, the problem can be perfectly a malformed content, so we need to see the expected structure and the sent one.

Comment: @gusman thz is the second part structure of data because firstly i want to hit web method so before that we have to hit url once the url hit it not show error 500 it will show 404,403 so please let me know how to hit url first

Comment: The web service will not enter to the function unless you sent the correct data, so you cannot "split" it in two phases, that 500 can be perfectly because the data structure cannot be deserialized and it throws an internal exception.

Comment: okay thanks gusman i am very new with soap but in restless we can easily get inside okay leave it that function takes so many arguments like                var fun(int i ,string str .......)

Comment: @gusman still i am not able to hit a web method

Comment: Sorry but without the input/output structure I can't help you any further...

Comment: @gusman can u provide some code so that i can hit webmthod

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-HttpClient-to-b9289836

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public List<plFairPriceShopDetails> FairPriceShopRequestAck(string FPSCode, string PLC_Code, string company_code, string device_mac_id, string app_version, DateTime download_date, string allocation_no, DateTime allocation_date, DateTime upload_date, int transactions_count)
    {
        clsAPIDetails _clsAPIDetails = new clsAPIDetails();
            return _clsAPIDetails.API_FairPriceShopList(_clsAPIDetails.FairPriceShopRequestAck(FPSCode, PLC_Code, company_code, device_mac_id, app_version, download_date, allocation_no, allocation_date, upload_date, transactions_count));
    }

Comment: @gusman any idea now?

Comment: Your method is missing the [ScriptService] attribute.

Comment: means if i placed  [ScriptService] attribute in method of webapi than it work for the above code that i mentioned httpclient right?

Comment: @Gusma i placed scriptservice but it still give me error 500  [ScriptService]
public class myFIrstSoapMethod : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    public myFIrstSoapMethod () {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

Comment: before  responseObj = httpClientObj.PostAsJsonAsync("FairPriceShopRequestAck", val).Result; and changed to  responseObj = httpClientObj.GetAsync("HelloWorld").Result; also